# Maximum values in wherein clause of mysql

Tags: where-clause, max

Do anyone knows about how many values I can give in a where in clause? I get 25000 values in  a where in clause and mysql is unable to execute. Any thoughts? Awaiting for your thoughts

Answer (score 5):

Although this is old, it still shows up in search results so is worth answering.

There is no hard-coded maximum in MySQL for the length of a query. This includes all parts of the query such as the WHERE clause.

However, there is a value called max_allowed_packet which determines the largest query you can run on the MySQL server process. It isn't to do with the number of elements in the query, but the total length of the query. So

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycol IN (1,2,3);
```

is less likely to hit the limit than

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycal IN ('This string','That string','Tother string');
```

The value of max_allowed_packet is configurable from server to server. But almost certainly, if you find yourself hitting the limit because you're writing SQL statements of epic length (rather than dealing with binary data which is a legitimate reason to hit it), then you need to re-think your SQL.

Answer (score 2):

I think that if this restriction is a problem then you're doing something wrong.

Perhaps you could store the data from your where clause in a table and then join with it. This would probably be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is something with execution time.

I think you are doing soemthing like this: Correct me if i am wrong:

```
Select FROM table WHERE V1='A1' AND V2='A1' AND V3='A3' AND ... Vn='An'
```

There is always a efficient way how you can do your SELECT in your database. Working in a database is importent to keep in your mind that seconds are very importent.

If you can share how your query is look like, then we can help you making a efficient SELECT statement.

I wish u succes